# How to parse a JSON Array which have no array name

Tags: java, android

I have a json array which have no array name. How can I parse a JSON array which dont have a name?
This is my array

```
[
{
    "id": "13",
    "email": "jcheck1@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "jcheck",
    "last_name": "check",
    "country": "india",
    "city": "tvm",
    "zip_code": "695581",
    "phone": "4712584632",
    "status": "Success"
}
]
```

I tried to convert it to JSON object and also tried to get the String straightly from the array. But I got exceptions both time.

Comment: `JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json)` and then `JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject obj= array.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = obj.getString("id");
        String email = obj.getString("email");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(yourString);
JSONObject obj = array.JSONObject(0)
```

if you have more than one object:

```
int size = array.length();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   JSONObject obj = array.JSONObject(i);
}
```

Comment: I am not getting `JSONObject`  as `JSONOBject` and you got to many upvotes also.......... and another haven't single one. Is this fixed IPL? :D

Comment: @ Pankaj Kumar. I tried to set your answer, but you deleted it. :(, thanks to blackbelt also.

Answer (score 0):

```
String json = //your json array as string;
try {
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(json);
catch(JASONException e){
     Log.e("JSON", e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String finaljson=buffer.toString();

```
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(finaljson);

            int size = array.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                JSONObject j= array.getJSONObject(i);

                String Image =j.getString("Image");
                String ImageName=j.getString("Iname");
                String Rating=j.getString("Rating");
                String Description=j.getString("Description");
                return Image +"/"+ ImageName +"/"+ Rating +"/"+ Description;
            }
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of why this example is preferable compared to the existing accepted answer?